# In Java how to filter a list of class instances based on any of its property to get another in streams or in one line

Tags: java, java-stream

How to filter this using streams or any other way to write in one line instead of for-loop.

```
class Attribute {

  String name;
  String value;

  .. 
  //getter-setter

}

.. main
List<Attribute> list = populateAttributes();

for (Attribute attr : list) {

  if (attr.name == "some key") {
     return attr.value;
  }

}
```

I am interested to do so in 1 line since I will be reading that path from config and my generic code will traverse the dot sequence and invoke methods using reflection. So something like this `classpackage.getAttributes...(getValue where attr.getname == "somekey")`

Comment: Hint: start with comparing strings correctly, then look up the javadocs of `Stream.findFirst`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stream.filter() to filter the list with attributes whose attribute name matches your key and find the first attribute:

```
Optional<Attribute> attributeOptional = list.stream().filter(attr-> "some key".equals(attr.name).findFirst();
```

Edit: if you want the value out of the attribute then you can use Optional.map() to map found attribute to its value, and if's not found then some default value like null.

```
String value = list
                    .stream()
                    .filter(attr-> key.equals(attr.name))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(attribute -> attribute.value)
                    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<...>  newList = objectList.stream()
                       .filter(obj -> otherListOrSet.stream().anyMatch(other -> other.getIntValue.equals(obj.getIntValue)))
                       .toList();
```